# Sqlite this Query not supported in above 2.2 version in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have implemented this query in my project and Its working perfectly in < 2.2 version only.

If I try to run in version > 2.2 then this query is not working.

Can you give some idea for this?

**Query :**

> mCursor = db.rawQuery("select ROUND(delivarycharge) from
>   pincodedetails where ROUND(subtotal) <=( select ROUND(subtotal)  from
>   pincodedetails where ROUND(subtotal)>="+price+" and
>   resturantID="+selArgs+" limit 1) and resturantID="+selArgs+" and
>   ROUND(subtotal) >=( select ROUND(subtotal) from pincodedetails where
>   ROUND(subtotal)<="+price+" and resturantID="+selArgs+" limit 1)  order
>   by ROUND(subtotal) LIMIT 1", null);

Comment: have you received any errors? If so, post log

Comment: Hi lings no i didn't get any error but i didn't get update value i got first value only.But 2.2 version i got perfectly answer.

Comment: I think limit is not support in latest version?

Comment: check the sqlite specs site

Comment: chetan while running 4.0 String query used getting in result after i put in sqllite software tools value is correct get.But mcursor is not update value .i said 2.2 version above.but perfectly update value in 2.2 version below all emulator